Miracast Not Working While Electron App Running (RTSP Protocol Breaks)
I am experiencing an issue where Miracast stops working when my Electron app is running. Specifically, the RTSP protocol seems to break, causing the connection to fail.
Details:
Electron Version: 29.0.0
Operating System: Windows 10, 11
Architecture: x64
Last Known Working Electron Version: 28.0.0
Expected Behavior:
Miracast should remain connected and functional while the Electron app is running.
Actual Behavior:
Miracast fails to connect, and the RTSP protocol breaks when the Electron app is running.
Questions:
Has anyone else encountered this issue with Electron apps interfering with Miracast connections?
Are there any known workarounds or fixes for this issue?
Could this be related to any recent changes in Electron version 29.0.0 that affect network protocols or video streaming?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Steps Taken:
Verified the issue persists on both Windows 10 and Windows 11.
Confirmed that the issue does not occur with Electron version 28.0.0.

I dont know about miracast and electron in deep but did you look with wireshark maybe electron use a port that is also used by miracast. What ports you are used in your electron app?
